# Codeigniter Changing routes makes $this->uri->segment() not working

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes, uri, segment

I've altered routes.php

```
$route['category']='Home/category';
```

for making url look like www.website.com/category insteead of www.website.com/Home/category. Since Home is my default controller.
but if i am using `$this->uri->segment();` inside category function, its not working. this is my controller

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  public function category()
  {
     $value=$this->uri->segmet(3);
  }
}
```

And my url is `www.website.com/category/books`
I am getting result if I dont alter routes. But by altering routes, I need this to work. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: its uri->segment() . I typed here wrongly. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can debug what you have there by:

```
var_dump($this->uri->segment_array());
```

this will give you [array of all segments](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment) in URI.

Also you can try to debug with this method:

```
var_dump($this->uri->rsegment_array());
```

this will give you [array of all routed segments](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::rsegment) in URI

Respectivelly, you can use `$this->uri->segment()` or `$this->uri->rsegment()` what ever you find more appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 1):

hello please check segment spelling in your code

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  public function category()
  {
     $value=$this->uri->segmet(3); //wrong 
     $value=$this->uri->segment(3); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to load URL library and than if your URL is:

```
www.website.com/category/books
```

And you want to get `books` from URL than segment should be:

```
$value=$this->uri->segment(2); //books
```

Answer (score 0):

My URL libraries are in autoload. Anyway I solved it. I just configured my routes like this
`$route['category/(:any)']='Home/category/$1'`